# 429. N-ary Tree Level Order Traversal - std::bad_alloc

Tags: javascript, tree, tree-traversal

I am trying to solve the leetcode problem
[429. N-ary Tree Level Order Traversal](https://leetcode.com/problems/n-ary-tree-level-order-traversal/)

I have used the basic level order traversal concept as shown below

```js
var levelOrder = function(root) {
    let queue = [root, null];
    let result = [];
    let tmp = [];
    
    for(let i=0; i<queue.length; i++){
        let node = queue[i];
        
        if(!node){
            result.push(tmp);
            tmp = new Array();
            if(i !== queue.length-1) queue.push(null);
        }else{
             queue = [...queue, ...node.children];
            tmp.push(node.val);
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

I tried running the sample Test-Cases Provided:

#### TC-1

[image]

#### TC-2

[image]

### Problem

While submitting the same code I get to see the below error:
[image]

Can someone please explain what is going wrong here and what needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when the test case passes an empty tree to your function, i.e. `root` is `null`.

In that case, the loop keeps adding `null` values to the queue.

So add a `null` check in your function:

```
if (!root) return [];
```